# Testing "Login" with watir

Tags: watir

I'm starting to use watir.
I need to create a test script to login in the application.

The code bellow is the script from the page.

I saw some examples with buttons and links, but I don't know how to "submit"("onclick=SubmitForm() type=button value="Sign In") the information.

Answer (score 2):

If you post html of the form I could tell you more.

I guess this should work:

```
browser.button(:value => "Sign In").click
```

There is [Buttons](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Buttons) page in [Watir Tutorial](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Tutorial).